Building own scheduling software and the price estimation
I am not into software engineering myself and am curious if you can help me. I am writing a thesis for a ground handling company in aviation. The aim of my thesis is to recommend an improvement in the scheduling process where employees involved in flight handling are scheduled on flights. This process is currently done manually by the coordinators in Microsoft Whiteboard.
During this research, I found out that there should be a software that automatically schedules the employees on the flights, the following requirements this system should be able to: be able to load the real-time flights along with the changes that take place such as delays; automatically schedule the employees on the flights with the right amount of employees and qualifications per flight; it should also be able to schedule by task in addition to scheduling employees on flights; the software should interface with a mobile application that is on the employees' phones where their tasks are listed; the software should automatically store the data of which employees are scheduled on which flights.
Besides giving the company the choice of purchasing and implementing an existing software, I also give them the choice of having their own software built. I found out that this requires linear programming. I would like to hear your expertise on what else is needed to realise this.
Now my question is what the estimated costs will be for making a software like this for the company and whether it will be cheaper to purchase an existing software or buy a licence. For example, should I think of $500,000 or even more like a million?
Thanks in advance!

Think multiple or tens of millions. You need to look into whether this falls under airline standard operating procedures, and thus what level of regulation is required (both by law and custom). Consider that current rates in the US, it can cost more than a million dollars per dev team year, and this is a problem that is going to take multiple people years to manage all the glue code around the scheduling problem.

Actually scheduling is from a software engineering point of view the 'simple' bit. The difficult part is gathering all the data of planned and current arrival schedules, employee data, whats needed per flight, ideally other logistical constraints in the movement between tasks (which is currently handled subconsciously), what the dependencies are, how to handle if people don't follow the schedule, etc. And then getting it back out to everyone who needs to know.

This is one of those questions where the ask is simple (how to estimate this), but the answer is such a shocking order of magnitude more complex and involved that it is utterly unanswerable. You need experience as a software engineer, project manager, and business owner. Plus you need to deeply analyze the functional, legal, and business requirements. @user1937198 is on the right track. Not even professional software engineers can give you more than a "rough order of magnitude" estimate. Think: years and millions of dollars.

"I found out that this requires linear programming" - yep, you found out that one out of N problems which such a software system has to solve involves linear programming. Leaves still N-1 unsolved problem (to be honest, it still leaves N unsolved problems, because knowing  that a problem may require linear programming is hardly  a solution), But N different problems to solve is not a basis for any estimation, especially when not knowing N.

... in reality, however, the company will probably not really be interested in *"what will developing this software with all these features will cost us". They will ask "we have this time & budget, what can we get for it?", and "are there parts which do not cost us too much time and money but bring us a serious improvement"? I would recommend trying to focus on that persepective in your thesis - what are the current pain points in scheduling which should be solved first? A realistic cost estimation, however, will easily exceed the scope of your thesis.
